# How will the interaction between Android Navigation component and Viewmodel be?

Tags: android-viewmodel, android-architecture-navigation

An Android Viewmodel can either have the scope/lifespan of either an activity or fragment, but how will this work in a Navigation component?

Considering if I have the following scenario:

```
MainActivity 
 - Contains the NavHostFragment

CustomerListFragment 
 - Starting point for the navigation
 - On click of any customer in the list, will navigate the CustomerDetailsFragment

CustomerDetailsFragment
 - Contains a tab with 3 fragments: CustomerDetailFragment, CustomerContactFragment and CustomerOrderHistoryFragment

CustomerDetailFragment
 - Display customer general information such as name, age, gender, etc...
 - Get data from CustomerViewModel

CustomerContactFragment
 - Display customer address, tel, fax, etc
 - Get data from CustomerViewModel

CustomerOrderHistoryFragment
 - Display customer's order history
 - Get data from OrderHistoryViewModel
```

On the scenario above, is it possible to share the same instance of CustomerViewModel for CustomerDetailFragment and CustomerContactFragment?

If I wasn't using the navigation component, I could just make CustomerDetailsFragment an activity and init my viewmodel to that activity but since in Navigation we only have fragments, how can I best achieve this?

I though of:

```
public class CustomerDetailsFragment extends Fragment {
...
CustomerViewModel model = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(CustomerViewModel .class);
...
```

but how do I pass this instance of viewmodel to CustomerDetailFragment and CustomerContactFragment?

Or is there a better way to structure the code above to achieve the same result?

Comment: If you want to use same instance of viewmodel in CustomerDetailFragment and in CustomerContactFragment you need to attach it to your activity, i think it is the only option.
CustomerViewModel model = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(CustomerViewModel .class);
And it is a good solution.

Comment: In that case, if I have a much more bigger navigation_graph. Won't the CustomerViewModel lifespan be thoughout the whole navigation?

Comment: It will, it is all depends on what information you want share between fragments, You can have one MainViewModel that attached to your activity, this viewmodel will contain list of customers, and when user clicking on any customer you will pass the id of the customer to CustomerDetailsFragment, and from there to CustomerDetailFragment and CustomerContactFragment and each of them can retrieve the proper customer from MainViewModel customers list(it will be the same customer instance).

Answer (score 5):

You can use `parentFragment` as a store owner. Call this in your `Detail` and `Contact` fragments.

```
CustomerViewModel model = ViewModelProviders.of(getParentFragment()).get(CustomerViewModel.class);
```

Comment: And here I am again facing the same problem and you helped me again!

Comment: Excellent. This answers my comment above.

Comment: This strategy is falling apart now. Scoping to the nav host fragment is too inflexible. I want multiple instances of a viewmodel within a flow that are shared between some fragments only, but it's not possible

Answer (score 1):

your scenario is well supported by `ViewModel`.

You just need to get ViewModel with activity scope: `ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity).get(...`

More info here:
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing

Comment: How should the lifecycle of the viewmodel be handled with this strategy? When we navigate away from the customer section of the app, the CustomerViewModel will stay in memory until the user exits the app, unless we specifically clear it somehow

Comment: VM should stay in Activity scope (will be tied to its lifecycle)

Comment: Since there is only one activity if using Android Navigation, that means the whole app scope. I don't think thats a good idea as memory can never be released for a shared viewmodel

Comment: In this case, you should have parent fragment & child fragments - you should tie VM to parent fragment scope (instead of whole Activity)

Comment: Yeah that's what I went with